# Trouble rebuilding a StreamProvider to update its current data

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have a`Consumer<NotificationProvider>` and in its builder function a `StreamProvider<List<Item>>`.

Please note that the latter widget builds perfectly on its initial load.

`NotificationProvider` contains a list of notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging, ergo when I receive a notification, I push something into the class' List`and then call`notifyListeners()`.

Please also note that my NotificationProvider is doing a good job because I have a counter at my `AppBar` and it's updating whenever I receive one.

Now on to the meat and potato.

I'm trying to rebuild the StreamProvider whenever `NotificationProvider.addAlert()` is called. But somehow it's not working?

I also added `updateShouldNotify: (prev, next) => true,` but it didn't help one bit.

Please help. Thanks!

I also added `updateShouldNotify: (prev, next) => true,` on the StreamProvider properties but it didn't help one bit.

```
return Consumer<NotificationProvider>(
  builder: (context, provider, child) {
    return StreamProvider<ItemsProvider>(
      builder: (_) async* {
        ItemsProvider _itemsProvider = Provider.of<ItemsProvider>(context);
        await _itemsProvider.getItems();
        yield _itemsProvider;
      },
      child: LeContent(),
      updateShouldNotify: (prev, next) => true,
    );
  },
);
```

I expect the list to update whenever I receive an FCM notification

Comment: Your `provider` variable is not used. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: which provider?

NotificationProvider stores the notifications coming form FCM

ItemsProvider is used to store the items and has a function to call the api.

Comment: Additional: Somewhere up in the tree,  I have a ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ApiProvider, SomeProvider, ItemsProvider> that initializes ItemsProvider on the builder function

Comment: Your snippet has a variable named `provider`, that isn't used.

Comment: Ah. I didn't really need that provider's data. I am just relying on its notifyListeners() event. Is that what's wrong? A consumer's builder method will rebuild, right? Regardless whether you utilize the provider or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue by having a `StreamBuilder` in a `StatefulWidget`.

I have my fetcher as a separate `Future<T>` method which will be called on `initState` and on `didUpdateWidget()`.

Next, in my `StatefulWidget` class, I require something that will be used to validate on `didUpdateWidget()`'s `oldWidget.something != widget.something`.

In my case I used the length of the `NoticeProvider.notices` which will be incremented every time my FCM configuration triggers it.

in code:

```
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(_Body oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.alertLength != widget.alertLength) _fetchData();
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

_fetchData, will then call the api, transform the JSON, and add it to the `stream` using a `StreamController` which, in turn, update the UI.

I hope someone will be helped by this answer in the `Future`!

Answer (score 1):

The `builder` parameter is called exactly once for the entire life of the `StreamProvider`.

The fact that you called `Provider.of<ItemsProvider>` doesn't change anything here – the method still won't be called again, even if `ItemsProvider` changes.

If you insist in using `StreamProvider`, you'll need to somehow transform the `Provider.of` into a stream instead.

You can use a `StatefulWidget` to do so. Here's an example:

```dart
class ProviderToStream<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProviderToStream({Key key, this.builder, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueWidgetBuilder<Stream<T>> builder;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  _ProviderToStreamState<T> createState() => _ProviderToStreamState<T>();
}

class _ProviderToStreamState<T> extends State<ProviderToStream> {
  final StreamController<T> controller = StreamController<T>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    controller.add(Provider.of<T>(context));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, controller.stream, widget.child);
  }
}
```

You can then do:

```dart
ProviderToStream<Foo>(
  builder: (_, stream, __) {
    return StreamProvider(
      builder: (_) async* {
        await for (final value in stream) {
          // TODO: yield something
        }
      }
    );
  }
)
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try it out. Thanks Rémi