# How to update streamProvider stream based on other providers value

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I want to update StreamProvider stream, based on the value of the Provider. I arrived at this solution.

```
return Provider<SelectedDay>.value(
          value: selectedDay,
          child: ProviderToStream<SelectedDay>(
            builder: (_, dayStream, Widget child) {
              return StreamProvider<DailyHomeData>(
                initialData: DailyHomeData.defaultValues(DateTime.now()),
                create: (_) async* {
                  await for (final selectedDay in dayStream) {
                    yield await db
                        .dailyHomeDataStream(
                            dateTime: selectedDay.selectedDateTime)
                        .first;
                  }
                },
                child: MainPage(),
              );
            },                
          ),
        );
```

This is the providerToStream class, which i copied from here [Trouble rebuilding a StreamProvider to update its current data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57241349/trouble-rebuilding-a-streamprovider-to-update-its-current-data)

```
class ProviderToStream<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProviderToStream({Key key, this.builder, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueWidgetBuilder<Stream<T>> builder;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  _ProviderToStreamState<T> createState() => _ProviderToStreamState<T>();
}

class _ProviderToStreamState<T> extends State<ProviderToStream> {
  final StreamController<T> controller = StreamController<T>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    controller.add(Provider.of<T>(context));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, controller.stream, widget.child);
  }
}
```

And this is the error i get when i try to use it

```
type '(BuildContext, Stream<SelectedDay>, Widget) => StreamProvider<DailyHomeData>' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, Stream<dynamic>, Widget) => Widget'
```

Note: The code doesnt even work when i place a dummy widget inside the ProviderToStream widget.

```
 child: ProviderToStream<SelectedDay>(
              builder: (_, ___, Widget child) {
                return child;
              },
            ),
```

I also tried to force somehow the type in the builder, so that it is not dynamic, with no luck

```
   child: ProviderToStream<SelectedDay>(
              builder: (_, Stream<SelectedDay> dayStream, Widget child) {
                return child;
              },
            ),
```

Comment: what is `ValueWidgetBuilder`? can you also provide the typedef? What error message do you get for your last example where you explicitly specify the type?

Comment: According to the fltuter documentation, ValueWidgetBuilder is a widget whose content stays synced with a [ValueListenable]. The error i get is exactly the same one in all cases i provided.